# How to add check box control in AboutBox wxpython?

Tags: wxpython

I have desktop application in wxpython. User will get notification whenever there is new release available. I would like to create new beta update channel for specific customers. I was thinking of adding check box in the AboutBox. If check box is checked, then user will get update from beta location. There is no way to add check box or other controls in AboutBox. Is there any to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. But you can create your own about box by rolling your own dialog with `wx.Dialog`. Then you can put any widgets that you want to in your custom about box.